# What are some examples of generality?

Tags: design

The cover of the book [The Practice of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161586X) lists programming principles:

- Simplicity
- Clarity
- **Generality**

Intuitively I understand generality as preferring to solve the general problem rather than the specific form in which the problem presents itself. For example a sort function should be able to sort anything that is comparable instead of just ints. However, that seems like a contrived example.

What are some better examples of generality?

Comment: What do you find contrived about sorting a `Comparable`? It's an extremely good illustration of the valuable principle that a method which limits itself to using only some of the functionality of an argument should strive to make that limitation transparent by declaring the most general interface. I literally cannot think of a good reason *not* to do that.

Comment: @KilianFoth I mean contrived because we rarely need to implement sort ourselves. I'm hoping for more real-life practical examples.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: why does a good example has to be one which you have to implement by yourself? A generic sort function in your favorite framework is something you just *use*, and the fact you can use it for all different kinds of data types demonstrates its generality.

Comment: ... note also you question is a "list-of-things" question, which is typically seen as [too broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) by our community.

Comment: The *whole reason* why you rarely need to implement `sort` yourself is *because* there already exists a general `sort` function.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yeah, that's my point. I'm looking for examples of generality in the actual code we do write.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: if you are looking for examples in your own code, how shall we tell you? We don't know what code you or your team writes.

Comment: Generality is why web developers create a master template page, a header control, a partial view, etc. You write the HTML for that complicated menu system just once, then reference it from the pages that need it. Without generality you'd write each page from top to bottom, menus and all.

Answer (score 1):

The book defines generality as:

> generality, which means they work well in a broad range of situations
> and adapt well as new situations arise

Sort() is a good example because the same language command is usually implemented to sort any sort of list with some way to pass in a sorting function. This means anyone wanting to sort a thing knows how to do it.

In your own code you should try and aim for the same result when you write objects and functions which might be used by other people. So for example say our product is a web shop and I write :

```
public class Checkout
{
   Buy(Order o) {...}
}
```

I want it to work for any order. I don't want

```
public class Checkout
{
   Buy(Order o) {...}
   BuyAtChristmas(Order o) {...}
   BuyAtRamadan(Order o) {...}
}
```

Instead I would either have sub classes of order, or different types of checkout all implementing the same myCheckOut.Buy(order);

This makes it easy for the next level up to be programmed and the code more flexible overall.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd address an incidental issue about "generality".

General facilities are things like "general purpose computers" or "programming languages".

The goal for most programmers is not quite to maximise "generality", but to economise on the concepts involved in the program, and to broadly economise on the amount of source code necessary to express those concepts.

Source code that is overly specialised is often conceptually over-specialised as well, so that there is not only a large amount of excess code in such a case, but a large number of distinctions in code between things that others might prefer to think of as one thing, or as a single class of things whose individual details are not usually (or not ever) important.

I struggle to think of a compelling example offhand, but we've probably all at some point been pleased to eliminate thousands of lines of code, by consolidating a large number of distinct methods into one method with a few parameters which vary relatively minor details of how the method works, or consolidated a number of different data structures conveniently into one.

But there is another pitfall complementary to over-specialisation, which is over-generalisation.

A sign of this can be source code where alterations in a particular locality affect or disrupt too many other things at once.

Generality can, paradoxically, result in source code that is difficult to adapt incrementally to additional cases which were not considered at the time of the "general" design. You can end up with a "generality" that is actually finely tuned to a large number of special cases, rather than a generality that is implicitly capable of coping with additional cases not considered in its design and therefore flexible.

Because the desirable kind of generality copes with something that isn't foreseen, a design having this quality is often coincidence, or the product of past experience and natural selection, rather than the product of pure thought or rational evaluation at the outset.

Also, single procedures might deal with too many parameters and small variations in workings so that it is no longer clear to a reader how a single procedure operates in any given case.

Or data structures might end up with highly abstract names for fields, which don't correspond with any normal use of language or any normal opinion about their similarity. For example, things as dissimilar as "sales orders" and "disciplinary records" might end up being generalised into "documents" with a "party name" and "notes" fields.

At an extreme, you find programmers ending up implementing special programming languages or complicated engines and "frameworks" of their own design. This is often something for which they have no flair or experience, and the result poor or liable to be a failure.

The point of all this is that usually a balance of generality is sought, where there are the right number of concepts involved in the design of the application, and where the source code is neither gratuitous about making unnecessary distinctions, nor too terse that it loses it's quality as human-readable material and loses any natural (i.e. 1-to-1) correspondence to the concepts the staff work with.

You see this principle expressed in other fields, such as when Einstein said physics should be "as simple as possible, but no simpler".

Complicated professional judgments are involved, and often the same thing needs to be judged repeatedly (by the same programmer, and by others) to find a reasonable balance in a particular context.

There isn't just one direction you can travel, towards "more generality", where the code is sure to improve and become clearer, and the workings of the application better.